# No response after adding JWT authentication with Postman?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, jwt, postman, asp.net-core-webapi

I am trying to add JWT authentication to my ASP.NET Core Web API.

This is what I added to the `ConfigureService` method:

```
services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
.AddJwtBearer(options =>
{
    options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
    {
        ValidateIssuer = true,
        ValidateAudience = true,
        ValidateLifetime = true,
        ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
        ValidIssuer = Configuration["Jwt:Issuer"],
        ValidAudience = Configuration["Jwt:Issuer"],
        IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Configuration["Jwt:Key"]))
    };
});
```

And this line in the `Configure` method:

```
 app.UseAuthentication();
```

Of course I have added JWT settings in `appsettings.json`:

```
"Jwt": {
     "Key": "ThisismySecretKey",
     "Issuer": "https://localhost:44311/"
    }
```

This is the code that handles a post class to return the  jwt token :

```
[AllowAnonymous]
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult Login([FromBody]UserModel login)
{
    IActionResult response = Unauthorized();
    var user = AuthenticateUser(login);

    if (user != null)
    {
        var tokenString = GenerateJSONWebToken(user);
        response = Ok(new { token = tokenString });
    }

    return response;
}
```

And added an `[Authorize]` attribute to my `Get` method :

```
[HttpGet]
[Authorize]
public ActionResult<IEnumerable<string>> Get()
{
    return new string[] { "value1", "value2" };
}
```

The problem is when I call the endpoints from Postman, I don't get any response unless I remove the `Authorize` attribute!

[image: postman]

Comment: `The problem is when I call the endpoints from Postman, I don't get any response unless I remove the Authorize attribute!`-Are you posting the secret key with the request header?

Comment: Can you share the **GenerateJSONWebToken** method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that the reason for the issue was the SSL Certificate being set on in Postman:

[image: SSL certificate]

Answer (score 2):

I think the problem is your key, i've changed it and it worked. I am not sure but length could be problem.
Try with this,

```
"Jwt": {
 "Key": "THIS IS MY SECRET KEY DID YOU LIKE IT",
 "Issuer": "https://localhost:44311/"
}
```